# Is having dot as first character in static file directory not allowable in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Currently, I have the following config file in Google App Engine

```
application: jstock-affiliate
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
auto_id_policy: default

handlers:
- url: /.well-known
  static_dir: .well-known

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

When I access the following URLs in my local, both works fine

```
http://localhost:9080/.well-known/a.txt - OK
http://localhost:9080/static/a.txt - OK
```

However, after I deploy to Google App Engine, it is not fine for folder `.well-known`

```
http://jstock-affiliate.appspot.com/.well-known/a.txt - ERROR
http://jstock-affiliate.appspot.com/static/a.txt - OK
```

I need a dot as the first character in the folder name, due to https://medium.com/google-cloud/let-s-encrypt-with-app-engine-8047b0642895

May I know how I can resolve this issues?

Comment: It should work. I have named my project's `.well-known` static dir to be `letsencrypt`, but I don't see any issues with using a dotdir to serve as `static_dir` in app.

Comment: One small tip, better to use an escaped dot . `- url: /\.well-known`, since `url` param accepts an regex, you should use an escaped dot to match a dot character. An unescaped dot would match any single character except line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google App Engine has problem creating folder which starts with dot. The following config will help

```
handlers:
- url: /.well-known
  static_dir: well-known
```

Folder `well-known` need to be created, instead of folder `.well-known`.

Comment: I think you can access the well-know dir by specifying this `/kwell-known` url also.

Answer (score 0):

The new App Engine Flex environment does not provide a "handler" configuration in `app.yaml`. The only way I could make this work is to add a `location` directive to the `nginx-app.conf` file, while placing the `well-known` directory parallel to the `document_root` directory specified in `app.yaml` (basically at the application root directory):

```
location ^~ /.well-known/ {
    alias /app/well-known/;
}
```

I use `^~` matching so that the regex rule prohibiting serving directories starting with a dot does not match.

Comment: Look again at the `app.yaml` in the question. Is your answer applicable?